# ¿Porque no funciona el String.Format en una resta de textbox?

Tags: c#, webforms

Llevo horas tratando de ponerle puntos de miles al textbox de patrimonio, el cual proviene de una resta entre activos menos pasivos, pero al aprece cuando se resta ya deja de calcular, ¿por qué pasa esto?

```
protected void txtActivos_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double calc1 = 0;
        double calc2 = 0;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtActivos.Text) || 

    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPasivos.Text))
            {
                calc1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtActivos.Text);
                calc2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtPasivos.Text);
                var calcTotal = Convert.ToString(calc1 - calc2);
                txtPatrimonio.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", calcTotal);
            }

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente tengas que hacer un cast o un parseInt para hacer que las cadenas que capturas sean un valor numérico. Creo que sería con Int32.Parse,si no me equivoco. O veo que si que los conviertes a double...quizás un float o ver que realmente se cambia a valor numérico con console.write(variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String.Format trabaja sobre determinadas cosas.

En tu caso, C2 implica un valor de formato currency, pero esta esperando como variable un numero.

Como lo que le estas pasando es una cadena, no hace ningun tipo de transformacion, porque no sabe como formatear esa cadena, ya que vos le dijiste que formateara un numero.

Para solucionar esto, lo que tenes que hacer es:

```
calc1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtActivos.Text);
calc2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtPasivos.Text);
var calcTotal = calc1 - calc2;
txtPatrimonio.Text = String.Format("{0:C2}", calcTotal);
```

Ya que de esa forma, calcTotal va a ser un numero y format va a poder reconocerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias compadre, probe muchas opciones menos esta, porque no comprendía que es lo que estaba pasando. Esta lo solucionó.

Comment: yo prefiero .ToString()